# Mocking HTTP requests in ember-qunit

Tags: ember.js, mocking, qunit, ember-cli

In an ember-cli app, testing is done using ember-qunit.

I would like to mock HTTP requests, but have not been able to find a recommended way of doing this [in the documentation](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#testing).

I have [found this thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/http-mocking-for-ember-testing/2846/32) which discusses this, but it appears to be out of date (for ember-cli anyway).

How do you mock HTTP requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I mock HTTP requests. One improvement could be done by encapsulating `mockjax` with helper like:

```
function stubEndpointForHttpRequest(url, json) {
    $.mockjax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        responseText: json
    });
}
```

So you can easily switch for another library like `sinon` or whatever.

```
module('Integration - Signin Tests', {
    setup: function(){
        App = startApp();
    },
    teardown: function(){
        Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
        $.mockjaxClear(); // Don't forget to clear mockjax
    }
});

test('Signin with valid data', function(){
  expect(2);

  stubEndpointForHttpRequest('api_url', 'response_json');

  // Write your test
});
```

I Hope this helps

Comment: +1 and check. Thanks for the answer. A couple of stumbling blocks that I encountered, and others might find useful: (1) mockjax does *not* support cross domain API requests, let's them pass through. If this is the case for your app, change them for yours tests. (2) Mockjax does not need integration tests - unit tests work too `startApp` and `App.destroy` aren't necessary.