# Unit testing actions in ember controller that return promises

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-qunit, ic-ajax

I have a controller that performs an asynchronous operation, which I would like to test:

```
/*globals Ember, momnent*/
import { raw as icAjaxRaw } from 'ic-ajax';

//...

    actions: {
        foo: function() {
            var req = icAjaxRaw({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ApiUtils.apiUrl+'/dofoo',
                processData: false,
            });

            return req.then(
                function resolve(result) {
                    console.log(result.response);
                    this.set('fooLastDoneAt', moment());
                }.bind(this)
            );
        },
```

... and in the tests:

```
test('actions.foo', function() {
    expect(2);
    var ctrl = this.subject();
    var model = {
        fooLastDoneAt: moment().add(-10, 'days'),
    };
    ctrl.set('model', model);
    ok(ctrl.get('fooLastDoneAt').isBefore(moment().add(-1, 'days')), true, 'initial');
    ctrl.send('foo');
    ok(ctrl.get('fooLastDoneAt').isBefore(moment().add(-1, 'days')), false, 'updated date');
});
```

However, this inevitably results in an error being thrown, in another, unrelated, test case:

```
"Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object"[
```

which must be occurring because `this.set('fooLastDoneAt', moment());` is executed after this test case has finished, and the test runner has done a `teardown` for this module, and gone on to the next one; while the action is still executing.

Is there a way for me to wait for an action to complete, asynchronously, before moving on to the next step the unit test?

---

@kingpin2k suggests [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20810854/194982),
where you pass in a promise deferred object into the action.
However, in my app, the app itself would never do this,
and it seems like a fundamental problem if I need to modify my app source 
just so that it can be tested -
especially since it adds added complexity.

Are there any other ways to make the test execution wait for the action to complete?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for `QUnit` `start()` `stop()` functions.

Here is example of using taken from QUnit documentation:

```
QUnit.test( "a test", function( assert ) {
  QUnit.stop();
  asyncOp();
  setTimeout(function() {
    assert.equals( asyncOp.result, "someExpectedValue" );
    QUnit.start();
  }, 150 );
});
```

Also [ember-qunit](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-qunit) library covers this with `then`.

Here is example for `ember-qunit`

```
test('actions.foo', function() {
    expect(2);
    var ctrl = this.subject();
    var model = {
        fooLastDoneAt: moment().add(-10, 'days'),
    };
    ctrl.set('model', model);
    ok(ctrl.get('fooLastDoneAt').isBefore(moment().add(-1, 'days')), true, 'initial');
    ctrl.send('foo').then(function(){
      ok(ctrl.get('fooLastDoneAt').isBefore(moment().add(-1, 'days')), false, 'updated date');
    });
});
```

I didn't test the code so I hope it solves your problem

Comment: @ saygun thanks for answersing this question and my [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24751690/194982) ... haven't quite responded to the previous one, because I got stuck on this!

Comment: @ saygun Thanks for you answer. Falling back on using QUnit primitives like you suggest, works for my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24751690/194982) as property gets and function invocations return their promises.

Comment: `ctrl.send('foo').then(/* ... */)` does **not** work, because the return value of and a controller action, that has been invoked via .send() does not actually get returned. As @kingpin2k mentions [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20810854/194982), "send and sendAction are one way streets", hence my being stuck on this one. The solution to this still evades me!